# Matlab memory leak when forward propagating cell arrays or 3D matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, memory-leaks, quantum-computing

I'm having an issue with the way Matlab is dealing with forward multiplying matrices when there are a large number of them.

As a simplified example, i'd like to do x(ii + 1) = y(ii) * x(ii). However when the dimensions of the matrix are large, and there are a lot of them, the memory requirement grows exponentially, way out of range for what it should be.

Here's some example code, where according to the matlab memory profiler it's using 1e-07TB of RAM, which although isn't correct this loop often takes up 256GB of RAM.

```
function forward_test()
    K = 250; 
    dim = 1024;
    U = cell(K,1);

    for ii = 1 : K 
        U{ii} = rand(dim,dim) + (1i*rand(dim,dim));
    end

    r_tmp = cell(K + 1, 1); r_tmp{1} = eye(dim);
    for k = 1 : K 
        r_tmp{k+1} = U{k} * r_tmp{k}; % <--- this line is the issue
    end

    % convert the matrix to a 3D array, I'm certian there's a better way of doing this, but this is quick and dirty
    u_test = zeros(dim, dim, K);
    for ii = 1 : K
        u_test(:,:,ii) = U{ii};
    end

    % test the same operation on a 3D array, rather than a set of 2D maricies. 
    tmp2 = zeros(dim, dim, K + 1); tmp2(:,:,1) = eye(dim);
    for ii = 1 : K
        tmp2(:,:, ii + 1) =  U{ii} * tmp2(:,:,ii);
    end 


    for ii = 1 : numel(r_tmp)
        if ~(all(all(r_tmp{ii} == tmp2(:,:,ii))))
            error('Result missmatch!');
        end
    end
end
```

To check performance run:

```
profile off
profile -memory on
forward_test
profreport
```

Comment: I don't see the profiler claim outrageous memory usage, but `U`, `u_test`, and `tmp2` will *each* use `1024^2*250*8*2/1024^3` or ~ 4GB, which is quite likely to bog down your system.